# How to use if condition on a different data type?

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an array list of integers and I want to check if a specific data on that list is the same as the variable declared, however, if I use `if(variable == arraylist.get(i)` it wouldn't work, I tried to find the way to convert my list to integer but I can't find the right solution.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List reg = new ArrayList();
    //int add;
    reg.add(2);
    reg.add(5);
    reg.add(6);

    Random rand = new Random();
    int newReg = rand.nextInt(4)+1;
    for(int i = 0; i < reg.size(); i++){
        if(newReg == reg.get(i)){
            //do stuff
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Define "it wouldn't work" for me. What wouldn't work? What was the output from it? What error messages (if any) are coming up in the console?

Comment: You could try "List.contains()"

Comment: And what have you tried that didn't solve the issue ? I don't know any java but it seems after 2 minutes of research that you can specify a type for your list, which I guess would solve the issue. Or you could probably typecast as you compare...

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - incompatible types: int cannot be converted to boolean
 at chairmate.scrambler.ChairmateScrambler.main(ChairmateScrambler.java:27) @AJC24

Comment: @daniu it still doesn't work "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable intValue
  location: class java.lang.Object
 at chairmate.scrambler.ChairmateScrambler.main(ChairmateScrambler.java:27)"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I just tried your code and in Netbeans it shows an error in the line where you compare. The general rule is to never you "==" when comparing any reference types (unless you really want to check if its the same object), use equals() instead. The following works tho:

```
    List reg = new ArrayList();
    //int add;
    reg.add(2);
    reg.add(5);
    reg.add(6);

    Random rand = new Random();
    int newReg = rand.nextInt(4) + 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < reg.size(); i++) {
        if (reg.get(i).equals(newReg)) {
            System.out.println("aa");
        }
    }
```

Comment: `never you "==" when comparing any reference types` - OP is comparing integers. It's safe to compare integers using `==`. The problem is that their `List` is of raw type.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that autoboxing hides the conversion between primitve types and reference types in Java. It usually goes well, but in this case, you're comparing the object reference to an integer. Try the following:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> reg = new ArrayList<>();
    //int add;
    reg.add(2);
    reg.add(5);
    reg.add(6);

    Random rand = new Random();
    int newReg = rand.nextInt(4)+1;
    for(int i = 0; i < reg.size(); i++){
        if(newReg == reg.get(i).intValue()){
            //do stuff
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

when you do reg.get(i) it is returning object. you have multiple options here:
A. define list as integer list i.e List reg = new ArrayList();
B. type cast object to int.

preferred option is A.

Comment: Did you mean `List<Integer> reg = new ArrayList<Integer>();` as option A?